# Add "not" string into Transifex

Tags: feature-request, localization, russian-stackoverflow, international-sites, transifex

On the search result page if you exclude tags in filter, for example, [[дефект] -[локализация]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82+-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), there is not translated word "not".

> [image]

I didn't find this string neither in Transifex nor in traducir. Could you add it? So we will be able to translate this string.

**Related discussion on SOru:** [На странице поиска не переведён "not" при исключении метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8693/15479).